# AddClass to nth-element by function

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are working on a website where we have a Flash element that shows a couple of movies, and some HTML elements of video thumbs, of some other videos.

When viewing the next video, we want to highlight the thumb below, with a function that the Flash can call.

I'm thinking something like this: (This obviously doesn't work)

```
function highlightMovie(4) {
    $(".thumb-wrapper div").removeClass("active");
    //The "4" in the below line, comes from the "4" in the Function
    $(".thumb-wrapper div:nth-child(4)").addClass("active");
}
```

How do I do this? How can I call a function that doesn't have a predefined selector, but can select a nth-child??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you know what index it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function highlightMovie(number) {
    $(".thumb-wrapper div").removeClass("active");
    //The "4" in the below line, comes from the "4" in the Function
    $(".thumb-wrapper div:nth-child("+number+")").addClass("active");
}
```

not sure if that is this what you're asking?
what does not work?

Answer (score 1):

```
function highlightMovie(n) {
    $($(".thumb-wrapper div").removeClass("active").children()[n]).addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `ExternalInterface` to call from Flash to JavaScript with a reference to the video that has started playing.  Presumably there is some kind of shared ID system in your code that will let you easily identify which thumbnail to highlight.

**EDIT**: Try to answer the question this time...

So can't you just do:

```
function highlightMovie(index) {
    $(".thumb-wrapper div").removeClass("active");
    $(".thumb-wrapper div:nth-child("+index"+)").addClass("active"); 
}
```

I've not tested it, but can say right now that you can't use nth-child at all in IE 8 and lower.

Comment: That is not what I was asking for. Don't think about the Flash. How can I make function, where I can specify a number, that is a nth-child?

Comment: Is that closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

i would try using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call a JS function from AS.

pseudo js:

```
function highlightThumb (index) {
  thumbs = getAllThumbsElem();
  for (var i=0;i<thumbs.length;++i) {
    if (i == index) {
      highlightElement(i);
    }
    else {
      resetHiglight(i);
    }
  }
}
```